# Como puedo hacer para que un array se almacene dentro de otro array

Tags: php

Estoy empezando con PHP, no se como incluir el segundo array de forma correcta en el primero, o si hay una mejor forma de realizarlo.

El proyecto busca guardar en un array las tablas creadas en la base de datos y posteriormente en cada tabla guardar los campos que le corresponden a cada tabla, es decir un array anidado.

```php
$con = new Conexion(); $sql_tablas = "SELECT table_name AS nombre FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '" . $con->getBase() . "';";

$tablas = $con->ejecutarConsulta($sql_tablas); $array_tablas = []; $array_columnas = [];

foreach ($tablas as $fila) {  
    $nombre_tabla = ucfirst($fila[0]);   
    $sql_campos = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$fila[0]' AND table_schema = '" . $con->getBase() . "';";   
    $columnas = $con->ejecutarConsulta($sql_campos);  
    $array_tablas[] = $nombre_tabla; 
        foreach ($columnas as $key => $value) {
            $array_columnas[] = $value; 
        }
    $array_tablas[] = $array_columnas;
}
```

Se imprime así, con un array de más, la idea es que la tabla "Extensiones" vea los campos que tiene dicha tabla en la base de datos y posteriormente saber como podría leer dicho array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Extensiones
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => id
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ext
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => email
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => nombres
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => apellidos
                )

        )

)
```

Gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: te refieres a los arrays asociativos?